# How does the distanceFromLocation method work?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocation

I frequently use the `distanceFromLocation` method for `CLLocation` objects to get their distance from other locations. Enumerating through an array of CLLocations, I then compare each to my reference location using this method.

I'm curious to know the processing/memory implications for using `distanceFromLocation`, especially for a large number of `CLLocation` objects in succession. How does this method work - does it connect to the server to get the data, or does it calculate the distance based on some mathematical formula, such as the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)?

Is there a more efficient method to compare distances between 1 reference location and an array of CLLocation objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are likely are using the Spherical Law of Cosines instead of the Haversine ([why? see this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/4906/14315)).

If all you want to do is compare many points against one point to see which is closest, then maybe you don't care about the accuracy of the computed distance and just about performance.  In that case perhaps using Pythagoras' theorem would work for you.

All of these algorithms are detailed on [this web page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), which says in part:

```
If performance is an issue and accuracy less important, for small
distances Pythagoras’ theorem can be used on an equirectangular
projection:*
```

You could implement a function using Pythagoras' theorem then benchmark it against the one in CLLocation and against my implementation of [distanceInMetersFromRadians](https://github.com/progrmr/SDK_Utilities/blob/master/Utils/UtilitiesGeo.c) that uses the Spherical Law of Cosines to see how much performance difference there is.

Comment: It should be noted that the Haversine formula, and all Mercator based formulas that assume the earth is a spheroid (as used by Google, Apple and Bing maps) are approximations for distances and shouldn't be used for GIS length critical calculations where you need accurate on the ground measurements. It's good enough for 99% of apps to use Haversine and rely on the built in calculations however... it's +/- 1m for most applications with 0.1% error, which over short distances and away from the poles is fine. If you want dead accurate you need to calculate distances in UTM or Lambert projections.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> distanceFromLocation:
>
> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations.

So yes, I assume it is using the Haversine Formula (or a modification of it).

Comment: Also in the Location Awareness Programming Guide: Gathering location data is a power-intensive operation. It involves powering up the onboard radios and querying the available cell towers, Wi-Fi hotspots, or GPS satellites, which can take several seconds.

Comment: @petert I guess my question wasnt clear, I know that gathering location data is power-intensive. What I meant to ask was - Is using the `distanceFromLocation` method on a large array of location objects inefficient? Is there a better way to compare locations that is less CPU/memory intensive?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Instruments and measured it? Until you have done, it's pointless.

You can take shortcuts. Let's say you want the nearest point. Find a formula that gives you roughly the right result. Usually there's a square root involved, so get a formula for the square of the distance - that's quicker and works just as well. Find the nearest point with your formula. Now say the nearest point is 178.96 meters apart according to your formula. You can then check all points that are say less than 180 meters away with the exact formula.

Answer (score 0):

For small distances and on iOS 9, I have found that the values obtained by `distanceFromLocation` are reliably close to those found by the Vincenty formula using the WGS-84 ellipsoid. In my experience, they are accurate within about 7 or 8 significant figures.

A spherical model, such as the law of cosines or the Haversine formula, does not compare well for small distances.

For more information, see the [`geopy` documentation](http://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-geopy.distance) and a [table of values for comparison](https://gist.github.com/ezheidtmann/1d60ddead76273de21ebd1455492e25d).