# distanceFromLocation return different result between iOS 8 and iOS 9

Tags: ios8, location, ios9, distance, cllocation

I use `distanceFromLocation` method of *CLLocation* to calculate the distance between 2 locations as below. It returns different result between iOS 8 and iOS 9. 
Anyone know why? Thanks.

```
CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:39.861667 longitude:-104.673167];
CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:33.942500 longitude:-118.408075];

// Calculate distance between 2 locations
CLLocationDistance routeDistance = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];

NSLog(@"Distance A - B : %f", routeDistance);
```

==> Result: 
Distance A - B: 
iOS 8: **1383761**.019303 
iOS 9: **1387015**.203345

Comment: Maybe Apple decided to change the formula behind `distanceFromLocation ` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549534/how-does-the-distancefromlocation-method-work